# Excel manipulates invisible cells in Filtered Range

Tags: excel

I have a large table that contains a large data. Most of the time when I apply a filter to it i can manipulate and edit the filtered data with no problems. However sometimes(every 200th time perhaps...) when i select filtered range and try to paste in the selection some text - it seems like it has done the job but when I unfilter the table, the range that was edited is the range as it wasn't filtered at all. 
Example:

my data is A1:A10
the filtered range is the cells A1 and A10,
when I select the filtered range and paste a text, occasionally the whole A1:A10 range is changed.

Anyone faced this issue? 
the consequences are disastrous.
How will i avoid it in the future.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.
When the data is filtered, I select cells and want to apply some changes to it - what happens is that excel defines the rows range for manipulation as "upper row in selection to bottom row in selection":

the problem is that sometimes the row indexes are not consecutive(common issue when the data is not logically ordered in the first place) and excel treats the whole range in between the visible selected cells as the range for manipulation TOO.
It hapened to me occasionally only because my data is more or less ordered.

Example: a small table of numbers

```
**nums**
1
2
3
4
5
3
6
```

if i filter the nums table to show only 3s
it will show me this:

```
**nums**
3
3
```

when i select these two cells by dragging from one 3 to the other, paste the number 0 and unfilter the table back, the result will be

```
**nums**
1
2
0
0
0
0
6
```

because the cells inbetween the visible cells were in selected range too.

To prevent it, the solution is as Lior suggested:

Find & Select --> Go to... --> Visible cells only.

Answer (score 0):

After you select the column you want to edit use select visible cells only.
in the link there is an example of the copy you can use the same for the paste.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/copy-visible-cells-only-HA010244897.aspx

Comment: Thanks Lior, it helped. However every time I do this routine it works as desired so I desperately want to know that mistake I occasionally make.

Comment: I had this problem several time and never figure out why it is happend. i belive it is Microsoft bug.